# Regex: How to get all text besides HTML tags in specifix section?

Tags: regex

I'm trying use regex to get the text out of this content:

```
 `content` = 'Уважаемый {first_name},<br><br>\r\n\r\n
    Hello, Tere, <b>this is some <span style="italic">lorem ipsum</span></b><br><br>
    \r\n\r\nÖöbik lõõritas äiksega Ülemistel.',`
 `something else` = 'Lorem {last_name},<br><br>\r\n\r\n
    Said Boo, <b>I'm a scary ghost</b><br><br>
    \r\n\r\nJäääär tööööl lõõritas üllalt.',`
```

So, I'm trying to get all non-HTML tag text between `'content' = '` and `','`.
I've been looking around, but it seems that my regex-building skills are quite lacking.
What I have so far is this:

```
(?:`content` = ')(</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>)(?:',`)
```

But for obvious reasons it's not working correctly.

So, if anyone has some idea, how to get this regex working, you would be my personal hero.

Thank you!

EDIT:

The expected output of that regex would be this:

```
`content` = 'Уважаемый {first_name},
Hello, Tere, this is some lorem ipsum
Ööbik lõõritas äiksega Ülemistel.',`
`something else` = 'Lorem {last_name},<br><br>\r\n\r\n
Said Boo, <b>I'm a scary ghost</b><br><br>
\r\n\r\nJäääär tööööl lõõritas üllalt.',`
```

And it's not language-specific request, just pure ol' regex, one pass only..

Comment: Which language are you using? There may be easier ways to do this than using regex. Also, when asking for help with regex it would be nice if you could add expected output after the content is processed.

Comment: You could just match all the html tags with `(<[^>]*>)` and replace with `""`(nothing) to strip all the html out of the string, and there ya go!  You're left with only the text. - Without knowing the language you're using, that's the best I can help.

Comment: re:edit - updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to do in two steps. First, remove tags:

```
# python
s = ''.join(re.findall(u"(?u)[^<>]+(?=(?:<|$))", data))
```

which gives

```
`content` = 'Уважаемый {first_name},


Hello, Tere, this is some lorem ipsum


Ööbik lõõritas äiksega Ülemistel.',`
```

and then strip the quotes:

```
s = re.sub("(^[^']+')|('.*$)", '', s)
```

As per your edit, this gives the desired output:

```
 re.sub(r'<.+?>(?=[^`]+`\s+`)','', data)
```